Systemd runs my script after suspend, but the result is not the same as if I enter the command in a terminal
Due to some drivers issues, my screen only reappears after suspending my laptop if I enter the following command in a terminal: chvt 7; DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --auto. Therefore, I wrote a simple executable script.sh with the following content:
#!/bin/bash

chvt 7; DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --auto 

When my screen is black upon waking up from sleep (which is always the case), I switch to a different terminal with ctrl-alt-1 and type ./script.sh, which systematically brings my graphical session back to life.
In order to avoid this straightforward but tedious manipulation, I placed an executable script reviveScreen in /lib/systemd/system-sleep with the following content:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
    pre)
            #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending
    ;;
    post)
            #code execution AFTER resuming
            echo "1" >> /tmp/systemd-test
            /path/to/script.sh
            echo "2" >> /tmp/systemd-test
    ;;
esac

exit 0

The echo parts are only here to make sure that the script is being upon waking from sleep, which I can confirm by consulting the file /tmp/systemd-test.
So it looks like the command which brings back my screen is being executed, but nothing happens, the screen is still black...
Any idea how we can make this simple piece of code run automatically whenever the laptop wakes up from sleep?

Can you put set -x into script.sh and then redirect its output / stderr into /tmp/systemd-test (>>/tmp/systemd-test 2>&1)?
I also wonder if adding something like sleep 5 to script.sh would help

Thank you very much for your feedback! I had tried to add a sleep 5 in the reviveScreen script (without success), but hadn't tried inside script.sh, so did it. Unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Concerning redirecting the output of the script, I replaced the line /path/to/script.sh inside the reviveScreen script with your suggestion /path/to/script.sh >>/tmp/systemd-test 2>&1 and I get the following content in /tmp/systemd-test: "1; + sleep 5; + chvt 7; + DISPLAY=:0; + xrandr --auto; Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified; ; Can't open display :0; 2". In contrast, when I just run script.sh manually from a terminal I see the following: "+ sleep 5; + chvt 7; + DISPLAY=:0; + xrandr --auto". Any idea why the display :0 cannot be opened above?

Check what user the script is running as (e.g. put the id command in your script). My guess is that it's being run as a different user (maybe root).

Thanks for the suggestion! Indeed, systemd runs the script as root, whereas when I launch it in the terminal it is run by my username. I guess, the funny thing is that root has less authorization than a regular user in this case, which I'm sure has its reasons but it's kind of surprising to see something that root is not allowed to do... Anyway, thanks to your constructive feedback, I was able to have the script run by replacing /path/to/script.sh by sudo -u username -i /path/to/script.sh in the systemd script reviveScreen. Also found that a sleep of at least 0.3 sec was needed. Thanks!!
